# scrapinghub upload and use file

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapinghub

I uploaded my spider on **scrapyhub**. I understand how to upload with my *.txt file, but how do I use it?

My **setup.py** file looks like

```
setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'youtube_crawl': ['resources/Names.txt']
    },
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = youtube_crawl.settings']},
)
```

Then I want to use this **Name.txt**.

before uploading my spider looks like

```
def parse(self, response):
        with open('resources/Names.txt','rt') as f:
            for link in f:
                url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}".format(link)
                name = link.replace('+',' ')
                yield Request(url, meta={'name':name}, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=True)
```

**So my question is: how I can use my file on scraping hub?**

I tried this code but don't understand how it works, and how integrate it with my code =)

`data = pkgutil.get_data("youtube_crawl", "resources/Names.txt")`

The function returns a binary string that is the contents of the specified resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code:

```
data = pkgutil.get_data("youtube_crawl", "resources/Names.txt")
```

is equivalent to this block:

```
with open('resources/Names.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
f.closed
```

So now you could read the binary string line by line:

```
def parse(self, response):
    data = pkgutil.get_data("youtube_crawl", "resources/Names.txt")

    for link in data.split('\n'):
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}".format(link)
        name = link.replace('+',' ')
        yield Request(url,
                      meta={'name':name},
                      callback=self.parse_page,
                      dont_filter=True)
```

Take a look at Python 3 [pkgutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) or [inputoutput](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) doc pages for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I need !
I modified the code a little, because  it did not work much the way I needed it
       
        **data = pkgutil.get_data("youtube_crawl", "resources/Names.txt")
        data = data.decode("UTF-8")
        data = data.split('\r\n')**